# Sequential topological space equivalent definition.

Tags: general-topology

I admit it is homework, but I really need some hints about how to prove $2) \Rightarrow 1)$. I have been dwelling on this for days... I know how to prove $1) \Rightarrow 2)$ and I think it's too hard to prove $2) \Rightarrow 3)$. So I think I should use $1)$ as a base statement equivalent to other two statements. ([image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b4Qx.png))

> 16. Show that TFCAE for a topological space $(X, \tau):$
>
> 1. If $E \subseteq X$ and $x \in \bar{E}$, then there is a sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $E$ with $x_{n} \rightarrow x$.
> 2. If $x \in U \subseteq X$ and for every sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $X, x_{n} \rightarrow x$ implies that $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is eventually in $U$, then $x \in \mathring U$.
> 3. If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ where $Y$ is a topological space, $x \in X$, and for every sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $X, x_{n} \rightarrow x$ implies $f\left(x_{n}\right) \rightarrow f(x)$, then $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Do you define $\overline{E}$ as the intersection of all closed sets that include $E$?

Comment: @311411, yes. Equivalently, using nhood system, it means that $x \in \bar{E}$ if and only if every nhood about $x$ intersects $E$

Comment: What does the "C" in "TFCAE" stand for?

Comment: @user10354138 the following conditions are equivalent. That would be my guess…

Comment: All these conditions are not about $X$ bing sequential but Frechet-Urysohn. Just FYI. Sequential is a weaker condition still.

Comment: Ah, I thought we always omit "conditions"/"statements"/... nouns and just go for TFAE (at least Google think so -- it showed results for TFACE instead).  Maybe not.

Comment: It's only $(3) \implies (1)$ that needs a little thought. The other implications are routine.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma , thanks for this information about Frechet-Urysohn, my knowledge about topology is quite limited.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, could you give me some hints on $3) \Rightarrow 1)$?

Comment: If $x \in \overline{E}$ then WLOG $ x \notin E$. Define $f:X \to [0,1]$ to be $0$ on $E$ and $1$ outside $E$. Is $f$ continuous at $x$? So what does $(3)$ then imply?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Thank you for your hints, I have worked it out. It is the strangest proof I have ever met. So many "nested" logical terms, we have to be very careful about where we use contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(2)\Rightarrow(3)$ is not too hard: Suppose (2) and $x\in X$, $f\colon X\to Y$ satisfies $x_n\to x$ implies $f(x_n)\to f(x)$.  Let open $V\ni f(x)$, and we want to prove $f^{-1}V$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$.

Suppose $f^{-1}V$ is not a neighbourhood of $x$, i.e., $x\notin (f^{-1}V)^\circ$.  By (2), that means there exists a sequence $x_n\to x$ with infinitely many $x_n\notin f^{-1}V$.  Can you see why this is a contradiction?

Comment: Yes! I found I really had a hard time dealing with these “nested” logical statements...

Comment: I think I come across a problem, we have, for this function $f$, "$x_n \rightarrow x$" implies $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$. Then we get a sequence $f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x)$ , $f(x)$ is in $V$, but $f(x_n)$ not eventually in $V$. How can this result be a contradiction? it doesn't contradict 2)

Comment: Recall $x_n\notin f^{-1}V$ means $f(x_n)\notin V$.  But $V$ is an open neighbourhood of $f(x)$.  So $f(x_n)\not\to f(x)$, contradiction.